# How often do you have to move the outbreak marker in a chain reaction?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-legacy-season-1

So if an outbreak occurs, I do move the outbreak marker one forward. If this triggers a chain reaction in one city, I move it forward once more. But what happens if I have several chain reactions? Would I have to move the outbreak marker up to 8 times? The rule book is a bit ambiguous about this.

Comment: I added the Pandemic tag as the question is equally valid for it, too. Please revert is you feel otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You move it once per outbreak, chain reaction or otherwise.

The rules don't seem ambiguous to me:

> When a chain reaction outbreak occurs, first move the outbreaks marker
>   forward 1 space. Then, place cubes as above, except do not add a cube to
>   cities that have already had an outbreak (or a chain reaction outbreak) as
>   part of resolving the current Infection card.

You have to do all of this - moving the outbreak marker, and placing cubes - for *each* city that has a chain reaction outbreak.

Also, it says "when *a* chain reaction outbreak occurs" - as in, one outbreak. If it meant you only moved the marker one step even when there are many chain reaction outbreaks, it would presumably say "one or more" or otherwise clarify.

Comment: +1. Indeed, this means that you can go from no outbreaks to game over very quickly, if you have just a few cities next to each other with 3 cubes each on them.